# 3D Ellipsoids and Displaying Them

Tags: python

I am attempting to plot ellipsoids based off of a large data sets and 3D , I originally used VTK's vktParametricEllipsoid module to create it but you can not set it center nor could I add plot multiple of them in the same window. In the script I am also using plotly as well. I'm open to any tool that can help with creating and displaying the ellipsoids in 3 dimension as well as all in the same window and remain interactive

Comment: Bradley, good to have you here. Could you please be more specific, and add details of the problem you have, including a snippet of code, your attempts to solve this, or answers you may have found but wasn't able to use. More details on your development environment would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib has a 3d library you might consider. The addition of `%matplotlib notebook` lets you drag to the orientation you'd like. Here is some sample code from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.html):

```
%matplotlib notebook
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 5 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

x1 = 3 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) + 4
y1 = 5 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v)) + 7
z1 = 2 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) + 2

x2 = 5 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) -11
y2 = 6.6 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v)) - 3
z2 = 2 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) + 6

# Plot the surfaces
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='b', alpha = .2)
ax.plot_surface(x1, y1, z1, color='r', alpha = .1)
ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, color='g', alpha = .3)

plt.show()
```

[image]